# How to convert MySQL datetime field into timestamp using Ruby?

Tags: mysql, ruby, datetime

I have two fields:

```
last_modified : datetime
updated_at    : timestamp
```

updated_at is a new field which has just been added to the table, last_modified contains accurate dates.

I want to be able to loop through all of the rows in the table, selecting the last_modifed datetime, converting it into a timestamp and saving it in the new updated_at field.

Have no idea how to do this, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
update table_name set updated_at=unix_timestamp(last_modified);
```

I don't why you want to store same data twice. Storing same data twice may result into inconsistency.

If you want `timestamp` in your code, you can do that in code itself.

Comment: While this sounds like an appropriate answer - what about the consideration for timezone? What if the data in last_modified is not stored implicitly as UTC?

Comment: unix_timestamp retuns seconds from 1st Jan 0000Hrs UTC. Even if your machines timezone is different from UTC above function will adjust to that.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is called `some_table`, then you can put this in your migration's `up` class method:

```
execute 'UPDATE some_table SET updated_at = last_modifed'
```

MySQL should be able to convert from `datetime` to `timestamp` automatically. In an SQL SET clause, the columns are specific to a single row and the SET applies to all matched rows; without a WHERE clause the UPDATE applies to all rows in the table. Remember that SQL is set-based so everything operates on sets of rows and loops don't really fit the model.

I'm assuming that you're using ActiveRecord as you have a timestamp called `updated_at`. If you're not using ActiveRecord then you'll have to find another way to send the SQL UPDATE to the database.